using Bootstrap-Table in Ionic Angular
I'd like to use Bootstrap Table in my Ionic project. I think it's easy to use and very responsive, so perfect for Hybrid Web App. Moreover I'm porting my Angular project to Ionic, that already uses Bootstrap Table.
How can I do that?
I tried to install Bootstrap with npm
npm install jquery
npm install bootstrap
npm install bootstrap-table

and then add to angular.json
"scripts": [...,
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"                        
]

but I'm stuck here. To render the table I should do
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-table';

var table = jQuery("#table-id");
    table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
      data: table_rows,
      columns: table_columns,
    });

I tried without using jQuery in this way
var table = document.getElementById("table-id") 

but that gives the error
bootstrapTable is not a function
If I use jQuery, I get this error
reference error:Cannot access uninitialized variable
What's the right way to use that?

Is jQuery really necessary?
How can I correctly import bootstrap scripts?
How can I exec the function bootstrapTable()?

Thank you

I solved in this way: add the <script> tag programmatically. I know it's not the best solution, but it's the only working so far.
    var myScriptElement: HTMLScriptElement;

    // bootstrap table
    myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    myScriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement);    
    
    // extension bootstrap table export
    myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    myScriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement);        

    // extension bootstrap table locale    
    myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    myScriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement);      
    
    // extension bootstrap table export pdf
    myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    myScriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.29.0/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.umd.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement);      
    
    // extension bootstrap table mobile card
    myScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    myScriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/mobile/bootstrap-table-mobile.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(myScriptElement); 

